# Add multiple document.referral to one cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I wish set a tracking cookie for a new visitor to my site by reading the current cookie, and adding the current html, then once the visitor visits another web page adding the new url to the end of the last url.

I have managed to store one document.referrer in document.cookie and send it to the CRM software, but it only shows the last URL and is overwritten by the most current.

My most current effort, but no luck:

```
function setTrackingCookie() {
    var existingCookie = document.write(document.cookie);
    existingCookie += document.write(document.referrer);
    document.cookie = existingCookie;
}
```

Comment: `var existingCookie = document.write(document.cookie);` ... what is the value of `existingCookie` after this line of code - there you may find what you are doing wrong (besides using document.write in this decade)

Comment: Also, an ever increasing cookie is a great way to add ever increasing server load (at least until you hit the size limit). Cookies are sent with every HTTP request.

Comment: charlietfl suggested tracking GUID, and you have stated that a cookie may not be the most practical. Now I have an idea of what not to do, what method would you suggest to track page visits per visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies have small size limits that you might hit quickly for active users.

Also cookies get sent with every request so the bigger the cookie the bigger the overhead for all requests

A more practical approach would be set a small cookie that contains a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), then track pages that GUID visits on server side and store there

Comment: To create the GUID do I store it directly in the cookie? If so how would I track it from there?

Comment: yes then read it on all page requests on server and store GUID and route